# is there possible to give marginTop as much as views height at xml?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-percent-library

I have one `imageView` and I am trying to give it minus margin top as much as its `height / 2`. I can do it at programmatically but i wondred is it possible at xml also andorid published percentrelative layout . I don't know how to to do it or possible?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein what about the new percent support library (http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/support-library/features.html#percent) ?

Comment: @aga It must be a **new** feature I wasn't aware of. See, I'm still targetting API Level **18**.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I know it's a new feature, I didn't take a close look at it myself. Just thought you already looked at it and can tell why it isn't usable here. :)

Comment: I'm too concerned with Alarms being delivered **on time**. And, frankly, I'm not interested in the new Material design at all.

Answer (score 0):

**--Edit: As @aga suggests, there seems to be a way to achieve it via the [Percent Support Library](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/support-library/features.html#percent)--**

If you want to use this type of `imageView` more often throughout your application you could extend imageview and put your margin-code inside of it's onMeasure:

```
public class HalfMarginImageView extends ImageView {

    public HalfMarginImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) getLayoutParams()).topMargin = -getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
    }
}
```

for this to work the view must be part of a ViewGroup.Also make sure you use the constructor with AttributeSet, oltherwise you can't create the View from xml. Yo then just include a CustomView in your layout xml, select `HalfMarginImageView` and use it as normal imageView.

Comment: As @aga suggested, have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/support-library/features.html#percent

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Thanks, just saw it and edited my Post.